# Get URL from ahref using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

`<a href="#url" data-mc-cta="1" style="display:none">Link</a>`

In this above `a href` code, a random URL will be generated by advertising network javascript placed before `</head>` tag

I am trying to get the random URL value using JS code :

```
var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
alert(mcLink);
```

This code is placed before `</body>` tag. The problem is this above JS code getting value `#url` instead of real random URL value.

As far i know, Javascript work in sequence, so, first Ad network JS code will place url to `a href` tag and than my code will get the value but it not working as I think.

Comment: *This code is placed before </body> tag* - your code runs too soon.   While the AD code will be *initialised* first, it's unlikely it will run first as it will likely be set to run on "document ready" or after an additional ajax call.  As you're using jquery, you can wrap your code in doc.ready:  `$(()=> { var maxConvLink... })` or you can wrap it in a `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1500)` but you'd have to tweak the timeout value based on the AD code.

Comment: @freedomn-m document ready means using DOM?

Comment: Explained here:  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/  and https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: The issue here is: exactly *when* does the add code update the url.  You might need a [MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are different approaches to achieve the output. Choose the one that best suits your needs.*

**Using `Window.onload`**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
  alert(mcLink);    
}
```

**Using jQuery document ready function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
  alert(mcLink);    
});
```

in order to use the jQuery library, you will need to include it

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Using `DOMContentLoaded` event**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
  alert(mcLink);
});
```

**Using `setTimeout`:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
  alert(mcLink);
}, 1000);
```

**Using `setInterval`:**

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  if (maxConvLink) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
    alert(mcLink);
  }
}, 1000);
```

**Using `MutationObserver`**

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "href") {
      var maxConvLink = mutation.target;
      var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
      alert(mcLink);
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(targetNode, {
  attributes: true
});
```

**Using `IntersectionObserver`**

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "href") {
      var maxConvLink = mutation.target;
      var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
      alert(mcLink);
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(targetNode, {
  attributes: true
});
```

**Using `window.addEventListener`**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var maxConvLink = document.querySelector('a[data-mc-cta="1"]');
  var mcLink = maxConvLink.getAttribute("href");
  alert(mcLink);    
});
```